# Shift TextView to nextLine if no room in the currentLine

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a linearLayout with 10 textviews inside it, but the problem is that I fill them with values of my database, so the sizes are changing dynamically.

I want that if the next view to be shown doesnt fit in the linearlayout jump a line and be placed below the other ones.

Here is my xml code:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:background="#666"
            android:text="alfabetico"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:background="#666"
            android:text="botellas"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:background="#666"
            android:text="barato"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:background="#666"
            android:text="botana"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:background="#666"
            android:text="caro"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:background="#666"
            android:text="entradas"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:background="#666"
            android:text="especialidades"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:background="#666"
            android:text="postres"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:background="#666"
            android:text="refrescos"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:background="#666"
            android:text="shots"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you can share a picture of what you are trying to create?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create an adapter to inflate your data into text views, by this way size of your data never make problem and application generates TextView dynamically.

here is an example

change your LinearLayout to ListView

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>
```

put your TextView in another xml file

**row.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:background="#666"
    android:text=""
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"/>
```

create an adapter

```
class dataListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private List<String> items;

        dataListAdapter(List<String> items) {
            this.items = items;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return items.size();
        }

        public String getItem(int arg0) {
            return items.get(arg0);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View row;
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
            TextView title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title);
            title.setText(getItem(position));

            return (row);
        }
    }
}
```

in your activity bind a ListView Object to your ListView in xml and set the Adapter

**your Activity class**

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
dataListAdapter adapter = new dataListAdapter(/*fetch your data from data base and pass it to this constructor*/);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

because of I don't know your structure of your data in data base, in this sample I assume that data is simply `String`(I assume that because you need show some data in TextView). you can modify it if you need.

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with my question

Comment: your text of post before editing gives another idea about your question, it was seems you want to show unlimited items within activity. Editing causes clear the question concept

Comment: Let me think about it and give another answer to your question by editing my answer

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if this will work but this is what i've done.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tableRow"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:background="#666"
        android:text="especialidades"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:background="#666"
        android:text="postres"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:background="#666"
        android:text="refrescos"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:background="#666"
        android:text="shots"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:background="#666"
        android:text="entradas"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tableRow"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:background="#666"
        android:text="alfabetico"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:background="#666"
        android:text="botellas"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:background="#666"
        android:text="barato"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:background="#666"
        android:text="botana"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:background="#666"
        android:text="caro"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" />

</TableRow>
```

i put the textviews in tablerows. each tablerow has 5 textview and has a weightsum of 5. each textview has a gravity of center and weight of 1.

i guess what you could do at first is create a tablerow dynamically and add your textviews in it then add it on any layout(relative of linear). after getting five data, create another tablerow and repeat the process. i guess using this will be much easier than knowing if the textviews are already near the side of the screen if you only new 10 textviews.